# Highcharts remove grid

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that has been designed that I'm working on and I have a few questions.

First, can I remove the grid lines etc. from the grid and just show a stacked bar graph with no axis/ticks etc.

Here's a link to the designed graph: [UI of simple stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSWG.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can do that just check the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth)

Comment: example check this http://jsfiddle.net/L556bpv0/

Comment: check this if this is requirement http://jsfiddle.net/3o0Lkhsn/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply hide both axes to achieve the desired result:

```
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gspgunzj/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.visible

Comment: My experience with the visiblity switch is that it removes the grid, but it leaves the whitespace where the grid would be. It also removes plotlines which was how I was going to place the goal line in my drawing. Any other ideas? I'd like to remove the space where the grid would be and keep the plotline. (Looks like Deep 3015 came up with very close to what I want. Thanks though)